# Why am I getting an extra character (a dot or bullet point) at the beginning of my byte array?

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following code used to get xml from a DataSet into a byte array using UTF-8 encoding:

```
private static byte[] fGetXmlBytes(DataTable lvDataTable)
{
  XmlWriterSettings lvSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
  lvSettings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
  lvSettings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace;
  lvSettings.NewLineChars = String.Empty;

  using(MemoryStream lvMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
  using (XmlWriter lvWriter = XmlWriter.Create(lvMemoryStream, lvSettings))
  {
    lvDataTable.WriteXml(lvWriter, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
    //Lines used during debugging
    //byte[] lvXmlBytes = lvMemoryStream.GetBuffer();
    //String lsXml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(lvXmlBytes, 0, lvXmlBytes.Length);
    return lvMemoryStream.GetBuffer();
  }
}
```

I want a byte array because I subsequently pass the data to compression and encryption routines that work on byte arrays. Problem is I end up with an extra character at the start of the xml. Instead of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><etc....
```

I get

```
.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><etc....
```

Does anyone know why the character is there? Is there a way to prevent the character being added? Or to easily strip it out?

Colin

Comment: Please post the actual value of the extra character.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will have to use an `Encoding` class that doesn't emit a preamble. The object returned by `Encoding.UTF8` will emit a preamble, but you can create your own `UTF8Encoding` that doesn't emit a preamble like this:

```
lvSettings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
```

---

The UTF-8 preamble is the [UNICODE byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (U+FEFF) encoded using UTF-8. The purpose of the UNICODE byte order mark is to indicate the endianness (byte order) of the 16-bit code units of the stream. If the initial bytes in the stream are `0xEF 0xFF` the stream is big endian; otherwise, if the initial bytes are `0xFF 0xEF` the stream is little endian.

U+FEFF encoded using UTF-8 results in the bytes `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF` and somewhat ironically, because UTF-8 encodes into a sequence of 8-bit bytes, the byte order does no longer matter.

Answer (score 6):

Preamble perhaps? Info here: http://www.firstobject.com/dn_markutf8preamble.htm

Comment: Thanks Brian for the very quick response. That was it sure enough

Answer (score 0):

The extra character is the UTF-8 preamble. AFAIK you cannot prevent the preamble from being written to the stream. However, does it really matter? When the byte array is parsed back into XML, the preamble will be correctly interpreted without error, so you might as well just leave it in there.

Comment: We basically do Response.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])theBytes);Response.ContentType = "text/xml";).
The browser parses the xml, but it doesn't appear to like the preamble!

Answer (score 0):

I am doing mostly the same with this code and it works perfectly:

```
MemoryStream data = new MemoryStream(1000);
datatable.WriteXml(data);
return data.toArray();
```

Comment: Freddy,

Thanks for that. I tried it. It doesn't put in a preamble but it doesn't put in the xml declaration, or my table name, so I think I will stick with the XmlWriter

Colin